# My java code with final keyword has error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, final

```java
// final keyword usage 
package workarea;
    
final class demo {
        
    final int x=10;
    ////compile time exception here because ‘x’ is final type
    System.out.println("hello modified x value is:"+ x);
    final void m1()
    {
        int x=2;
        System.out.println("hello modified x value is:"+x);
    }

    void m2()
    {
        System.out.println("hello modified m2 x value is:"+x);
    }

    public static void main(String abc[])
    {   
        demo df=new demo();
        System.out.println("welcome");
        df.m1();
        df.m2();
    }
}
```

this is my code and the error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at workarea.demo.main(demo.java:24)
```

The error message is for the code line where main is mentioned
Help me correct this code

Comment: Please [edit] the post, format your code properly, highlight/mark the line causing the compilation error and add a [MRE]. From what I can infer, the problem is not related to the `final` keyword.

Comment: You cannot have `System.out.println("hello modified x value is:"+ x);` in the class. It must be in a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An initializer block may come in handy for you.  So where you have:

```
final int x=10;
 ////compile time exception here because ‘x’ is final type
System.out.println("hello modified x value is:"+ x);
```

instead do (with slight change to string message):

```
final int x=10;
{
    System.out.println("(in initializer block: x value is:"+ x);
}
```

This is an alternative to constructors or to supplement them as this code would be used in all constructors (if you were to add any).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("hello modified x value is:"+ x);
```

If you delete on the this line code your app will succesfully run

Answer (score 1):

Using function call to `System.out.println("hello modified x value is:"+ x);`is causing you the problem.

Because you are not allowed to do that in Class level scope. And it should happen in a block or other methods.

Answer (score 0):

For compile-time exception, It's good create and run the programms using any  Java IDE's -Eclipse,STS,Netbeans and IntelliJ for earlier compile detections .
In above code ,printing statement
`System.out.println("hello modified x value is:"+ x);`
should be in block or in a method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing here is in here you are trying to write a statement purely in the class body without having a method or instance initializer. In Java you can't do that.
So please include the below statement inside a method or a instance initlalizer.

```
System.out.println("hello modified x value is:"+ x);
```

**Alternative 1 (Using a method) :**

```
public void sampleMethod(){

   System.out.println("hello modified x value is:"+ x);

}
```

**Alternative 2 (Using an instance initialaizer):**

```
{

   System.out.println("hello modified x value is:"+ x);

}
```